# Is visual studio 2015 compatible with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2015

Can I use visual studio 2015 to build workflows for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a short answer **Yes** . once installing `Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015` you will be able to create a SharePoint 2013 Empty Project > then add item workflow.

[image]

If you missing `Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015` check [Office / SharePoint template missing in Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: Assuming I have the MS office dev tools for VS 2015, can I create said workflows from my machine? Or do I have to install visual studio on the sharepoint server? Ideally, I would like to install visual studio on my laptop so I dont have to remote into the sharepoint server.

Comment: See my brother , regarding your comment :  unfortunately, you can develop a SharePoint solution in a machine that didn't have SharePoint installed and if you tried to do this you will get this error "SharePoint must be installed on the local system to develop SharePoint solutions." ,

Comment: Meanwhile, By using the SharePoint development tools in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with Microsoft SharePoint 2013, however, you can create app for SharePoint solutions on a system by using a remote installation of SharePoint. You don't have to install SharePoint 2013 on your local system. This capability is known as remote development.

Comment: Fortunately, In SharePoint App / Add-In you can  Add a workflow to a SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in for more details check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx

Comment: Sharepoint and sql are installed locally. They are not hosted. Can i still use Visual Studio from my machine?

Comment: If you mean locally is your machine so the answer Yes you can do this and that what I have mentioned above  what's the problem for that ?! , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification ,

Comment: I mean locally on the lan. Not on my machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48514/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-jes516).

Comment: as a short answer and as I have mentioned above : NO  you can't develop a SharePoint solution from your PC that not have sharepoint but you can develop a SharePoint add-in (workflow to a SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in ) as I have mentioned above and mentioned here at Microsoft link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx please read my comments carefully ! and if you need any clarification let's continue at chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48514/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-jes516